# Can I reference field item & label in node.html.twig?

Tags: theming, entities, 8

In Drupal 8, I defined a content type (say example) and made a separate template for it: node--example.html.twig.

I wonder if I can reference the item or label of a specify field in node--example.html.twig, instead of reference them in field.html.twig? By which I mean can I use something like the following, which I know is not working?

```
{{ content.field_example_field.label }}
```

Comment: Item(as a Field API field attached to an entity) yes, but not the label due to the structure. Although maybe something like {{ content.myfield.und[0]['#title'] }}could potentially work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find the label somewhere inside of `content`, then the code, which will prepare the label for rendering did not run at this point.

If you are inside the node twig, then there is a fully loaded node object. You can use this to get the field definition and the label:

```
{{ node.field_myfield.fieldDefinition.label }}
```

Or the first field item:

```
{{ node.field_myfield.0.value }}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thx.